# Json object is bashed

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I trying to read a Json object, it came as a response from a web service REST using CURL(), when I try to show the content I just have especial characters as if the data is bashed.

when I consult the URL on the navigator I got a Json Object with not problems but if I execute the curl usin the same url I get junk data, and when I apply json_decode() it result NULL

the url is http://sigpac.magrama.es/fega/ServiciosVisorSigpac/query/recinfo/20/1/0/0/1/1/1.json

my php code

```
<?php
    $url ="http://sigpac.magrama.es/fega/ServiciosVisorSigpac/query/recinfo/20/1/0/0/1/1/1.json"; 
    $client = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($client);
    if($response === false)
    {
      echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($client);
    }
    else {
      echo 'Operación completada sin errores<br>';
      $getData = json_decode($response,true);
      var_dump($getData);
    }
  curl_close($client);
 ?>
```

I hope you can help me. I will appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

It's gzipped, add the proper [`CURLOPT_ENCODING`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option, like:

```
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
```

---

From the manual:

> CURLOPT_ENCODING - The contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and "gzip". If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent.

Comment: I don't know who you are but I LOVE YOU!!!! It works, thank you thank you thank you!!!!